# Importing dates from other workbook gives Error 9

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on an excel file with a bunch of macros/formulas and the most important thing is calculate NETWORKDAYS for each period but I can't store Holidays inside the excel workbook because this file is meant to be uploaded to the main server, so what I'm doing is creating a external sheet on the same folder that stores all holidays.

So I've tried importing the file this way but I keep getting Error 9, even with the exact filepath to the sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub duplicadorVac()
'main file stored in the same folder
Dim planillaDestino As Worksheet
Set planillaDestino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hojaDest")

Dim planillaFuente As Worksheet
Set planillaFuente = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hojaFuente")

'holidays worksheet stored in the same folder
Dim planillaFeriados As Workbook
Dim hojaFeriados As Worksheet
Set planillaFeriados = Workbooks("C:\...\arch_pba\planillaFeriados.xlsm")
Set hojaFeriados = planillaFeriados.Worksheets("hojaFeriados")

'AND FUNCTIONS AND CODE GO HERE

'MAIN TASK
planillaDestino.Range("F2:F" & filaIndiceDestino).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(D2,C2,[planillaFeriados.xlsm]hojaFeriados!$A$2:A)" ' total days

End Sub
```

What I hope is if I could set a foolproof path like '...\excel_pba\planillaFormula.xlsm' (if it happens to be moved from the original folder) to the stored holidays and then run the formula as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the workbook with `Workbooks.Open`. A closed workbook is not a member of the `Workbooks` collection, so you get a `Subscript out of range` error.

```
Set planillaFeriados = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\arch_pba\planillaFeriados.xlsm")
```

Comment: It was that easy, thank you!. Though is there any way to avoid getting the file actually open?

Comment: Yes there are some workarounds - several examples here on SO that show how to query/extract data from a closed workbook